# What is the best way to describe a event which was well organized so much that there was no tension while event was going on?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, writing-advice, academic-writing

I am looking for the right words to describe an event which was meticulously planned and executed. I want to stress on the fact that the managers / professors overlooking the event were relaxed as there no mishaps like everything went well as planned.

Is it right to say "the event was meticulously planned with attention to detail, so much that the whole event felt like breeze" ? What is the better way to say this ?

Comment: Forgive me and would that not be better Asked in Learning or Writing?

Answer (score 2):

Using idioms (somewhat colorful/colloquial):

'The event was planned *down to the last detail* and *ran (as) smooth as silk.*'

Changing the subject (going active):

'After months of meticulous planning, seeing to every last detail, *the committee breezed through* the event, a complete success enjoyed by patrons and planners alike.'

Matter of fact:

'The event was *well planned,* down to the last detail, and ran smoothly throughout.'

Briefly:

'*The event ran smoothly* as planned, down to the last detail.'

There are many wording options; that is subjective, and I offered a few to show different takes on it, not great wording options. But regarding word/phrase usage, I did find "felt like a breeze" used in similar contexts online, often in this structure (paraphrased for example): 'After all that planning, the wedding felt like a breeze.' Or with naming specific tasks: 'After preparing all those invitations, hosting the party felt like a breeze.'

Sources:

1. Merriam-Webster ([down to the last detail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20to%20the%20smallest%2Flast%2Ftiniest%20detail))
2. Collins English Dictionary ([well planned](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/well-planned))

Answer (score 1):

[Cakewalk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cakewalk): (Wiktionary)(idiomatic) Something that is easy or simple, or that does not present a great challenge.

- "The event was so meticulously planned, it felt like a cakewalk"

[Cinch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cinch): ((Wiktionary) Something that is very easy to do.

- "The event was so meticulously planned, it was a cinch"